# Where place my custom files magento if i want developed design files for custom extension

Tags: magento

Where place my custom files in magento if i want develop extension in `design/frontend/base/default` or `design/frontend/default/default`. I think be logic place it to `design/frontend/default/default`, but i am find opinion about that good practice place it to `design/frontend/base/default`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what Magento versions will you support.
If you plan to make your extension work on Magento 1.3 and lower than you should put your design files in `default/default`.
If your extension is for versions 1.4+ then place them in `base/default`.
You can see other tips and tricks that might help you when building an extension [in here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8345/146)